# Rmarkdown gives me error loading the qq-plot function

Tags: r, r-markdown

When i run my code everyhing is on, when i try to cenvert it in PDF it gives me an error. DO I need to install some other packages?

````
##Normality of the variables

#QQ-plot

```{r}
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
with(Melanoma, qqPlot(age, dist="norm", id.method="y", id.n=2, 
  labels=rownames(Melanoma), main="qq-plot Age"))
with(Melanoma, qqPlot(thickness, dist="norm", id.method="y", id.n=2, 
  labels=rownames(Melanoma), main="qq-plot Thickness"))
with(Melanoma, qqPlot(time, dist="norm", id.method="y", id.n=2, 
  labels=rownames(Melanoma), main="qq-plot Time"))
```
The variable "age" seems to follow a normal distribution, we can't say the same thing for the ariables "thickness" and "time".
#Saphiro-Wilk test
In order to be more precise I performed a Saphiro-Wilk test
```{r}
normalityTest(~age, test="shapiro.test", data=Melanoma)
```

```{r}
normalityTest(~thickness, test="shapiro.test", data=Melanoma)
```

```{r}
normalityTest(~time, test="shapiro.test", data=Melanoma)
```
We can see that, only the variables "time" and "age" seems to follow a normal distribution.
````

Comment: What error? I think your object `Melanoma` is in your Envrionment, but you have to call it explicitly when you render your RMD file.

Comment: Rmarkdown can't find "qqplot" function

Comment: you have to call the library in your RMD file, so (I think it's the `car` library) `library(car)` at the begin of the RMD code chunck.

Comment: ggplot is in the standard R librady! the markdown editor  recognise it, whn i try to knit it the software tells me that he can't find the function

Comment: But you call `qqPlot` instead of `qqplot` in your example

Comment: i'm writing the code using Rcmdr and i use it's markdown output, in Rcmdr works, in R studio it doesn't

Comment: Error in sort(y) : 
  l'argomento "y"  non è specificato e non ha un valore predefinito